# Finite power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, exponential-function

I'm a student and I'm looking for a solution for the following finite power series:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{n!} x^n
$$

By "solution" I meant expansion of the series and finding a closed form representation of it (without the sum). Thanks to everyone for the replies! The solution with the Taylor remainder was what I needed.

Comment: If the upper limit $m\to\infty$, then the series is the Maclaurin expansion of $e^x$

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What do you mean by "solution"? Also, you're more likely to receive good answers if you post your work to this point.

Comment: In agreement with @Travis, I’d point out that ordinarily, it’s only equations that have solutions, and an equation requires the verb “$=$”. Maybe you meant a *description* of the finite sum?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Lubin I think that's probably the intention, in which case OP might find illuminating the question I linked in the previous comment.

Comment: I don't believe that the finite sum has any closed form that works for all $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only think you can get a "closed" for the finite sum by using the Taylor reminder. That is if the real function $f$ is $m+1$ times differentiable at the point $a$ then 
$$
f(x) = f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a) + \cdots +  \frac{f^{(m)}(a)}{m!}(x-a)^m + \frac{f^{(m+1)}(\xi)}{(m+1)!}(x-a)^{m+1}
$$
where $\xi$ is obtained by the mean value theorem and belongs between $a$ and $x$.

Then in your case, clearly $f(x)= e^x$ and $a=0$, which gives 
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{n!}x^n  + \frac{e^{\xi}}{(m+1)!}x^{m+1}
$$
For a $\xi$ such that $|\xi|<|x|$ ( which of course gives that $\xi$ depends entirely on $x$). Thus 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{n!} x^n=   e^x - \frac{e^{\xi}}{(m+1)!}x^{m+1}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me solve my problem. I learned a lot about Taylor series and the remainder.

Comment: That is great @Alf , I am glad I could help !!